# How to show only specific item when filtering collapsible set in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi I am using jQuery mobile to build a mobile web application.
And I am learning from [this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/filterable/).

**Specifically, how can I display children when I filter in collapsible set?**

For example, from the example code, when I enter `cats`, it gives me back `Animal` blocks. I need to click it then see the `cats`. Is there any ways I can display only `cats` (or in another words: how can auto expand corresponding blocks?) when I search cats.

```
<form>
<input data-type="search" id="searchForCollapsibleSetChildren">
</form>
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-filter="true" data-children="> div, > div div ul li" data-inset="true" id="collapsiblesetForFilterChildren" data-input="#searchForCollapsibleSetChildren">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Animals Cats Dogs Lizards snakes">
        <h3>Animals</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Cats">Cats</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Dogs">Dogs</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Lizards">Lizards</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Animals Snakes">Snakes</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Cars Acura Audi BMW Cadillac">
        <h3>Cars</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Acura">Acura</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Audi">Audi</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars BMW">BMW</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Cars Cadillac">Cadillac</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-filtertext="Planets Earth Jupiter Mars Mercury">
        <h3>Planets</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Earth">Earth</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Jupiter">Jupiter</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Mars">Mars</li>
            <li data-filtertext="Planets Mercury">Mercury</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filterablefilter` event (see [API](https://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#event-filter)) to execute some JS after each search:

```
$(document).on("filterablefilter", "#collapsiblesetForFilterChildren", function(event)
{
    var results = $("[data-role=collapsible]:visible");
    if (results.length !== 0)
        $(results[0]).collapsible("expand");
});
```

This code expands the first collapsible in the result set (if present).

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j5krxota/1/)